# Python 2 Print emoji in a sentence as rectangles

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, emoji

I have this  (*loudly crying face* and *clapping hand* emoji character) in a `string.txt` file (encoded in `utf-8`).

I am trying to print it out into the default python IDLE, in a sentence.

```
with open('string.txt','r') as f:
    string = f.read()
```

The code:

```
>>> string
'\xf0\x9f\x98\xad\xf0\x9f\x91\x8f\xf0\x9f\x8f\xbb'

>>> print string
ðﾟﾘﾭðﾟﾑﾏðﾟﾏﾻ

>>> print string.decode('utf-8')
    # <-- this is the output I want in a middle of sentence
```

That's the output I want (rectangles). The tricky part is that I want them in middle of a sentence. So:

```
>>> print 'The string is: {}!'.format(string.decode('utf-8')) # will get error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#81>", line 1, in <module>
    print 'The string is: {}!'.format(string.decode('utf-8'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Got an error. But if I don't decode it, it works:

```
>>> print 'The string is: {}!'.format(string)
The string is: ðﾟﾘﾭðﾟﾑﾏðﾟﾏﾻ!
```

It did not raise any error, but I don't want this output. I want the rectangles.

How should I solve this issue so it will behave like this:

```
>>> print 'The string is: {}!'.format(magical_string)
The string is: !
```

Preferred to not use any 3rd party library.

**EDIT:**

My Operating System: *Windows 7* (preferred solution for all Windows 7-10)

Python: *2.7*

Comment: Naming a variable `string` is probably not a good idea seeing as there is a commonly used python module called `string`.

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: @KindStranger the name is just so it's obvious that it's a string though thanks for the tip :) , as for the OS, I am Windows 7 but I create my scripts for Windows 7-10.

Comment: It seems that you are using Python 2, right? It is important to mention that in a question concerning unicode and string encodings, because Python 2 and Python 3 do not behave the same way in this respect.

Comment: @zvone yep, I just realized I did not mention in my question my python version. I am going to do it now.

Comment: Either way, the problem is probably caused by the fact that your console is using an encoding in which the characters you want to print do not exist.

Comment: @zvone I am not using the console but the python's default IDLE (I mentioned it in the second sentence of my post). I know that printing out into a console is an even bigger headache.

Comment: If you must use Python 2, you should take a look at https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html But anyway, try `print u'The string is: {}!'.format(string.decode('utf-8'))`. That's not ideal, but it should work. I can't test it because I'm on my phone, and I rarely use Python 2 these days, so I'm a bit rusty. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a setting of your IDE, and not really a python issue.

When I save the first line of your question into a txt file and read it:

Copied from terminal:

```
>>> open('test.txt').read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\joost\Desktop\pythontests\venv\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 19: character maps to <undefined>
>>> open('test.txt', encoding='utf-8').read()
'I have this  (loudly crying\n'
>>>
```

As a picture:

[image]

Perhaps specify your encoding when opening the file?

Comment: `TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`. Is this error because I am using Python 2.7 and you are using Python 3?

Comment: @ProgramerBeginner Yes, the built-in `open` doesn't accept an encoding arg in Python 2. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open Or migrate to Python 3, where Unicode handling is a lot saner. ;)

Comment: Uh, I theoretically can migrate to python 3, but would prefer a python 2 solution.

Comment: @ProgramerBeginner Understood. But remember, official Python 2 support finishes in 15 months, so you need to seriously think about migrating in the not too distant future.